# Printing hex integer by casting to char* and using "%s" in sprintf

Tags: c, string, embedded

I'm reading in two 32 bit registers and trying to put it inside a string buffer using the following:

```
sprintf (buffer, "%s-%s", ((char*)(in32(REGISTER1))) , (char*)(in32(REGISTER2)));
```

Can the hex value read in from the registers not be typecast as a pointer to a char and be printed into the buffer as above?

Comment: What is the return type of in32()? If it's a 32-bit integer, do not cast to char *, and use "%x-%x" for your format string (or "%08x-%08x")

Comment: You should really try to come up with a better title than "Why doesn't this work?" I tried to think of one but I don't really understand low-level C well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [craig65535](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255551/craig65535) implies in a comment above, the problem is most likely with this phrase:

> the hex value read in from the registers

I doubt that you're reading in a hex value; rather, you're reading in an integer. If you want to store a hex representation *of* that integer in a string, you'd use the `%X` format specifier:

```
sprintf (buffer, "%08X-%08X", in32(REGISTER1), in32(REGISTER2));
```

(The `8` means "use a width of eight characters"; the `0` means "left-pad with zeroes if the value is such that the width is less than eight".)

The only way you could validly cast to `char *` is if the integer value in the register is actually a pointer to some memory location where you've stored a string; but that is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf(buffer, "%08x-%08x", REGISTER1, REGISTER2);`
-- that's assuming you want the register addresses in your buffer. If your intention is to read the contents of the registers, adjust accordingly. The point though is you cannot simply call a number a char* and get the number out of it, but `sprintf()` (and all printf-like functions) can convert value bases for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the others answers suggest, you can convert your integer to a string hex representation with `sprintf` using `%X`.
But as you didn't said what compiler you use or what the length of integer or long is, you could get unexpected results.
On a 16bit controller `sprintf (buffer, "%08X-%08X", in32(REGISTER1),in32(REGISTER2));` would fail.

This should work on the most plattforms, as sprintf assume long values as arguments, and the arguments are always casted to longs.

```
sprintf (buffer, "%08lX-%08lX", (long)in32(REGISTER1), (long)in32(REGISTER2));
```